# MFA rule is still triggered while it should not and where to file relevant log

Tags: windows

I configure ADFS Access Control Policies like 
this.

[image]

My purpose:

- Allow all users login from intranet without triggering MFA rules.
- Allow users belong to group "No MFA" login from internet without triggering MFA rules.
- Other users login from internet except users belong to group "No MFA" is allowed to login but MFA rules will be triggered.

However, when I login with an account belong to "No MFA" group from internet, the MFA rule is still triggered. The question is my setting correct or not and what log I should enable and where I can find information regarding the ACP for troubleshooting.

Thanks in advance,
Luat